# Drawing parallel lines and dots in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I am struggling to place labels and no fill circles in my latex code. I wish to have the following output:

[image]

I have managed to come up with the following code:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{calc}

\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        PC/.style={black, thick},
        dot/.style={circle,fill=black,minimum size=4pt,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=-1pt}
        ]
        
        
        % Define linear parameters 
        \def\PCint{5}   %Y-intercept 
        \def\PCslp{-1}   %Slope 
        \def\PC{\x,{\PCslp*\x+\PCint}}
        
        \draw[PC, domain=0:5] 
        plot (\PC);
        
        
        % Define linear parameters 
        \def\PCint{4}   %Y-intercept 
        \def\PCslp{-1}   %Slope 
        \def\PC{\x,{\PCslp*\x+\PCint}}
        
        \draw[PC, domain=0:5] 
        plot (\PC)
        node [right] {margin};
        
        \draw [domain=0:5]
        let
        \p1=(61.28041pt, 26.23682pt),
        \n1={\y1-\PCslp*\x1} in
        
        % points the plot should pass through...
        node [dot] at (\x1,\y1) {}
        node [dot] at (0,\n1) {}
        node [dot] at (0,1) {}
        node [dot] at (1,0) {}
        node [dot] at (1.3,0.5) {}
        node [dot] at (1.7,0) {}
        node [dot] at (3,-1) {}
        node [dot] at (4,-2) {}
            
        % first try for a plot...
        plot[yshift=\n1] (\x,\PCslp*\x)
        node [right,yshift=\n1] {$-2/||w||$};
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which is producing something not good looking as shown in the picture below:
[image]

I am kindly requesting for assistance on how I can best improve my diagram.

Comment: Hi! At least for me, it's unclear 1. how do you build the third row, 2. where do you want to put the circle, 3. which is exactly the problem. To draw unfilled circle, just say `circle, draw` instead of `circle, fill`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a way to do it. Main ideas:

#### Define some coordinates

Using polar coordinates `(angle:radius)`. So the main reference point is where line H begins.

```
    % ~~~ start coordinates A, A1, A2; B == direction
    \coordinate (A)     at (0,0); 
    \coordinate (A1)    at (60:7mm); 
    \coordinate (A2)    at (240:7mm); 
    \coordinate (B) at (-30:5cm);
```

#### Use pos on path

- shift the node to label the line a bit to the left
- draw the line, here between `(A)` and `(B)`
- put an invisible node at the end, to handle the margin-things later

```
    % ~~~ one longer path ~~~~
    \draw 
        node[xshift=-4mm] {$H$} 
        (A) -- (B) 
        node(X)[pos=1] {} % invisible node at end
        ;
```

Also putting circles on the other pathes like `node[pos=.2,dc] {}   % the circles, shifted along path`  using one of the defined styles.

#### Styles

The styles were introduced step by step, with some amount of re-use.

```
        c/.style={circle,draw},%            open circles
        cf/.style={c,fill=black},%          filled circles
```

#### Using the hidden nodes

... to draw the arrows and to put the margin-label later.

```
    % ~~~ arrows below ~~~~~~~
    \draw [<->] (X1) -- (X2);
    
    % ~~~ label below ~~~~~~
    \node[align=center,xshift=8mm,yshift=-2mm] at (X) 
        {margin\\$\frac{-2}{\|\omega\|}$};
```

To account for multi-line use `align=center` in the formatting options, and `\\` inside the `{ }` at desired line-breaks.

#### Finally ...

putting some dots, using polar coordinates, referenced to "H".

---

[image: result]

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}

 \begin{tikzpicture}[
        c/.style={circle,draw},%            open circles
        cf/.style={c,fill=black},%          filled circles
        dc/.style={c,double},%              upper circles
        dcf/.style={dc,fill=black},%        lower circles
        > = {Stealth}%                      arrow heads
    ]
    % ~~~ start coordinates A, A1, A2; B == direction
    \coordinate (A)     at (0,0); 
    \coordinate (A1)    at (60:7mm); 
    \coordinate (A2)    at (240:7mm); 
    \coordinate (B) at (-30:5cm); 
 
    % ~~~ one longer path ~~~~
    \draw 
        node[xshift=-4mm] {$H$} 
        (A) -- (B) 
        node(X)[pos=1] {} % invisible node at end
        ;
    
    % ~~~ upper parallel ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \draw 
        (A1) node[xshift=-3mm] {$H_1$} 
         -- +(B)% using coordinate B as relative coordinate
        node[pos=.2,dc] {}  % the circles, shifted along path    
        node[pos=.7,dc] {}       
        node(X1)[pos=.95,inner sep=0] {} % invisible node
         ;
         
    % ~~~ lower parallel ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \draw 
        (A2) node[xshift=-3mm] {$H_2$} 
         -- +(B)
        node[pos=.2,dcf] {} % filled     
        node[pos=.7,dcf] {}      
        node(X2)[pos=.95,inner sep=0] {} % invisible node
         ;

    % ~~~ arrows below ~~~~~~~
    \draw [<->] (X1) -- (X2);
    
    % ~~~ label below ~~~~~~
    \node[align=center,xshift=8mm,yshift=-2mm] at (X) 
        {margin\\$\frac{-2}{\|\omega\|}$};
        
    % ~~~ some dots ~~~~~~~
    \draw   (30:1.5)    node[c] {}
            (5:2.5)     node[c] {}
            (8:4)       node[c] {}
            (-12:5)     node[c] {}
    ;
    
    \draw   (270:2)     node[cf] {}
            (300:2)     node[cf] {}
            (305:3)     node[cf] {}
            (312:4)     node[cf] {}
    ;
 \end{tikzpicture}
 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's an alternative solution that places the dots in relation to the lines by specifying a ratio along the line and a distance from the line (between the border and the line).

The nodes are placed [explicitly along the lines](https://tikz.dev/tikz-shapes#sec-17.8) via a fraction of the distance. The distance uses the same `line direction` key we've used specify the angle of our diagram.

If you don't like the angle of the lines, change the `-30` inside `line direction`'s definition (though, the `H` nodes as well as the margin node will need some adjustments if you change it too much).

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\tikzset{
  fake double/.style 2 args={
    label={[#1, minimum size={#2}]center:}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  o/.style={shape=circle, draw, inner sep=+0pt, minimum size=+2mm},
  O/.style={o,       fake double={o}{+2.6mm}},
  c/.style={o, fill, draw=none},
  C/.style={o, fill, fake double={o}{+2.6mm}},
  >=Latex,
  line direction/.style={rotate=-30, shift={(90:#1)}}]
\foreach \i/\t in {-1/H_2, 0/H, 1/H_1}
  \draw[line direction=\i*.75]
        (0, 5) coordinate (st\i) node[above left]{$\t$}
    -- coordinate[pos=.95] (mk\i) +(right:5) coordinate (en\i);
\node[below right, align=center] at (en0) {margin\\$-2/\|\omega\|$};
\draw[<->] (mk-1) -- (mk1);
\path (st-1) -- (en-1)
  node foreach \Pos in {.3333, .8} [C, pos=\Pos]{}
  node foreach \Pos/\Dist in {.2/5, .45/2, .7/2, .4/8, .65/7, .85/4}
    [c, below, pos=\Pos, line direction=-\Dist mm] {};
\path (st1) -- (en1)
  node foreach \Pos in {.3333, .8} [O, pos=\Pos]{}
  node foreach \Pos/\Dist in {.2/5, .4/2, .45/8, .7/7, .85/5}
    [o, above, pos=\Pos, line direction=\Dist mm] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]